# Does nautilus encrypt files on BitLocker encrypted drive?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, nautilus, encryption

I have an Ubuntu 23.10/Windows 11 dual-boot setup with one of my SSDs and an HDD, both encrypted using BitLocker's New Encryption Mode (XTS-AES). And I read that Linux systems natively don't have support for BitLocker. What I'm confused about is, whenever I use Nautilus to copy files onto these encrypted drives on Ubuntu (using Nautilus), I can't quite tell if those files are actually being encrypted. You see, when I turned BitLocker on, Windows asked if I want to encrypt the whole drive or just the files on the drive. If I had chosen not to encrypt the entire drive, deleted files on these drives wouldn't get encrypted. So, I figured that it's possible for a drive to be encrypted and some files on it to not be encrypted.

So, are the files that I paste/create on the BitLocker encrypted drives when using Ubuntu actually being encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm confused about is, whenever I use Nautilus to copy files onto these encrypted drives on Ubuntu (using Nautilus), I can't quite tell if those files are actually being encrypted.

They are.

> You see, when I turned BitLocker on, Windows asked if I want to encrypt the whole drive or just the files on the drive. If I had chosen not to encrypt the entire drive, deleted files on these drives wouldn't get encrypted. So, I figured that it's possible for a drive to be encrypted and some files on it to not be encrypted.

No, you can't have mix of encrypted and unencrypted files.

What you're asked is if you want to encrypt the entire disk space or the used space. If there's nothing on the disk previously, encrypting only used space is good. If there's already data that you need to protect on the drive, you should select to encrypt everything - otherwise clear text file remnants may be left available.

Any new writes will be encrypted.